# Divide calculations among multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I've just started working with threads in java. I have a simple algorithm that does a lot of calculations. What I need to do is to divide those calculations among different threads. It looks like this:

```
while(...) {
      ....
      doCalculations(rangeStart, rangeEnd);
}
```

And what I want to do is something like this:

```
while(...) {
     ...
     // Notify N threads to start calculations in specific range

     // Wait for them to finish calculating

     // Check results

     ... Repeat

}
```

Calculating threads don't have to have a critical section or be synchronized between each other, because they don't change any shared variables.

What I can't figure out is how to order threads to start and wait them to finish.

thread[n].start() and thread[n].join() throws an exception.

Thank you!

Comment: What exception are you getting? And please post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) for a better explanation./

Comment: I think what you need is [`ExecutorCompletionService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use an ExecutorService

```
private static final int procs = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
private final ExecutorService es = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(procs);

int tasks = ....
int blockSize = (tasks + procss -1) / procs;
List<Future<Results>> futures = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < procs; i++) {
    int start = i * blockSize;
    int end = Math.min(tasks, (i + 1) * blockSize);
    futures.add(es.submit(new Task(start, end));
}

for(Future<Result> future: futures) {
    Result result = future.get();
    // check/accumulate result.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a CountDownLatch to start, and another CountDownLatch to finish:

```
CountDownLatch start = new CountDownLatch(1);
CountDownLatch finish = new CountDownLatch(NUMBER_OF_THREADS);
start.countDown();
finish.await();
```

And in each worker thread:

```
start.await();
// do the computation
finish.countDown();
```

And if you need to do that several times, then a `CyclicBarrier` is probably what you should use.

Answer (score 0):

Learn [MapReduce](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2006/08/01.html) and [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/).  I think the could be a better approach than rolling your own, at the cost of greater dependencies.